# CSS: flexbox gallery that proportionally scales its contents until they fit, without overflowing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, image-gallery

I am trying to make a gallery of 16:9 images that constrain to both the width and the height of their container. They should automatically wrap into however many rows or columns best scales them. I know how to do this via JS, but I would much rather choose a CSS solution if it's possible.

```css
/* vvv For demonstration purposes vvv */

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

body,
body * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

div.video img.test {
  /* So we can see the images. */
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

div.container {
  /* The actual size of this container will be responsive. */
  /* This basically simulates the aspect ratio for this fiddle, I guess. */
  width: 50vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: white;
}


/* ^^^ For demonstration purposes ^^^ */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2vmin;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1vmin;
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video-container .video {
  flex: 1;
  /* flex-basis: 24%; */
}

.video-container .video>* {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>help :c</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>
      Header
    </h1>
    <div>
      This is just some body text. The quick brown fox or whatever. Basically, the gallery should fit in the remaining space beneath this element.
    </div>
    <div class="video-container">
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And below is the relevant CSS. `.video-container` is the gallery. `.video` contains the images (which are video thumbnails).

```css
.video-container {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1vmin;
    align-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}
.video-container .video {
    flex: 1;
    /* flex-basis: 24%; */
}
.video-container .video > * {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Basically, [this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BZOr.png). I can achieve it by setting flex-basis on the items inside the flexbox. However, this is not responsive; for example, if I set flex-basis to 25% (well, 24%), then I will always get 4 columns. And if the images do not perfectly divide by 4, then the [last row grows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9heS.png); they need to stay the same size! And if there's, say, 40 images, then there would be ten rows, which would exceed the bounds of the container! ([This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHAJj.png) is what that behavior looks like.)

How do I do this? Is this something that requires JS? Should I be using grid instead of flex?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom row is growing because of `flex: 1;` on `.video-container .video`. Instead, just use a calculated `width` that factors in your `gap: 1vmin` for spacing.

So for example, you could set `.video-container .video` to `width: calc(25% - 1vmin)`.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

body,
body * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div.video img.test {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

div.container {
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2vmin;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1vmin;
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.video-container .video {
  width: calc(25% - 1vmin);
}

.video-container .video>* {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>help :c</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>
      Header
    </h1>
    <div>
      This is just some body text. The quick brown fox or whatever. Basically, the gallery should fit in the remaining space beneath this element.
    </div>
    <div class="video-container">
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="video">
        <img width="1920" height="1080" class="test" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. But that will still limit the number of columns, in this case to 4 columns, right? Can I not, for example, have the `div.video` elements grow until it best fits the container, thus making the number of rows or columns automatic?

Comment: @Avoyt 4 columns, yes. Your question about "having the `div.video` elements grow until it best fits in the container" is unclear. All images should fit in the container with 4 columns as long as `img{max-width: 100%;}` is set. This allows them to scale. The row count is constantly changing as you add more, but the columns will not, and there is no CSS function to tell elements to fill in a certain space with `x` amount of columns.

Comment: Ahh, I see; I suppose I was hoping for a way for the number of columns to increase or decrease to fit the images inside without overflowing. In your example, if you add more `div.video` elements, they don't shrink, but instead overflow. I have a limited amount of space I can fill with these `div.video` elements. I want to fill it the best I can. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Avoyt It makes sense. & there will be now overflow on your `img`'s as long as you use `img{max-width: 100%;}`.

Comment: [But it does overflow.](https://i.imgur.com/SloIpKa.png) To be clear, I mean it's overflowing out the bottom of `div.video-container`. I have a limited amount of space I can fill with these `div.video` elements.

Comment: @Avoyt That is because the `width` and `height` on `div.container` and the enormous width and height on the images.

Comment: @Avoyt Using `vh` and `vw` for units on the `container` is not very responsive in terms of flexibility. I typically only use those units on larger screens if I need to have a fullscreen video or something like that. If you remove those, you should be fine.